# Blackberry : detect profile mode

Tags: blackberry

I play a ringtone in my application for notification message

```
 InputStream stream = (InputStream)this.getClass()
 .getResourceAsStream("/storm.mp3");
  p = Manager.createPlayer(stream, "audio/x-wav");
  p.realize();
  p.prefetch();
  p.start();
```

However, it keeps playing even when the device is in silent mode or vibrate mode. How can I detect the device profile mode? That is whether if it is in normal, silent or vibrate  mode?

Comment: I think that [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1894075/862724) has what you need. Do not forget searching before posting.

Answer (score 0):

The [Profiles](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/profiles/Profiles.html) class allows you to query some aspects of the profile.  It is new in OS 7.1, so this won't help you for most BlackBerry users.